# How to subclass UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios4

I honestly don't know how to subclass a UITableView. I'm super confused and looking for whatever help I can get. How do I go about "subclassing" a UITableView? Reason I need to do it is because I need for the table to respond to touches on the background so that keyboards can be hidden. I've tried googling but couldn't find anything. Any help is extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most of the time you shouldn't need to subclass `UITableView`, so see if you can avoid doing so first. If you *absolutely* have to, create a subclass that inherits from `UITableView` and override the touch-related methods in the implementation:

```
// MyTableView.h

@interface MyTableView : UITableView {
}

@end

// MyTableView.m

@implementation MyTableView

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    [super touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
}

@end
```

Comment: One thing to add: Don't forget to implement `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` if necessary

Comment: I think it's worth elaborating on why you shouldn't need to subclass UITableView. The reason is that you can accomplish a lot of customization by passing customized cells to a standard UITableView instance (via cellForRowAtIndexPath) . In other words, your controller acts as the data source for your table, and when the table is being set up, it will ask your controller for cells. This is what the standard tutorials are trying explain.

Answer (score -4):

In your .h file declare it as a subclass:

```
@interface myViewController: UITableViewController
```

Then implement the UITableViewController delegate methods:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDelegate

To detect touches on a cell write your logic in the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: The question was regarding UITableView not UITableViewController