# UITableView appearance setBackgroundColor not working for plain table styles when compiled on macOS High Sierra

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, macos-high-sierra

I have successfully been using `[[UITableView appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` for my iOS app under both Xcode 8 and 9 and macOS 10.12 (Sierra).  This is with both simulator and phone hardware running iOS 11.

When I updated to 10.13, that code stopped functioning for any table view that isn't the "grouped" style.  If I set the background color on a specific instance, then it works fine.

I have tried reinstalling Xcode, cleaning the build, verifying that I have no local changes from the source as built (and works) on other computers.  Changing between the 10.3 and 11.0 SDKs also makes no difference.

According to [Set UITableView BackgroundColor Universally with UIAppearance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751067/set-uitableview-backgroundcolor-universally-with-uiappearance) UITableView may not support this feature, but that answer is a few years old now and that this has been working for me seems to contradict it.

A good answer would explain what difference in my environment caused this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The default background color for plain tables has evidently changed.  Looking at the storyboard file, in Xcode 8.3.3 it generated this:

```
<color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
```

In Xcode 9 it changed to:

```
<color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
```

So this can be "fixed" by going to every table and resetting the background color to "default", but then your project won't work correctly in the other environment.