# How to subclass a UITableViewCell?

Tags: swift, uitableview, outlet

I got this old post: [How to subclass UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445840/how-to-subclass-uitableview) and this old video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FfZGKx4BYVU but this did not help me. What I want is very simple, I got an UITableViewController with dynamic cells. I want to outlet those cells. This is only possible if I "subclass" it. I made another file what looks like this:

```
import UIKit

class CreateChannelCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

But I still can not add those outlets from the UITableViewController to this file. My cells needs to be dynamic. I think I am only missing one step, but what step is that? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the right way to subclass. But if you are using Storyboards or Xib files then you need to reference the `CreateChannelCell` in the `UITableView` that you created and where the `CreateChannelCell` is located.

You need to select the cell and then go to `CustomClass` and write the name of your class there ... in this case `CreateChannelCell`

[image: Here you need to go at your Cell and declare <code>CreateChannelCell</code>]

If you are not using Storyboards or Xib's please see the answer provided by Code Different

Answer (score 2):

You need to register your custom class with the table view.

If the cell is on the same scene as your table view:

```
tableView.register(MyCustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

If you designed it on a different nib ( say `MyCustomCell.xib`):

```
let nib = UINib(nibName:@"MyCustomCell" bundle: .main)
tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

Comment: strange, it doesn't seem to hook up the `IBOutlet`s when I try it.